# How to I make a sql query check if the username is part of the email?

Tags: sql

So I want to select all users where username is contained in the email

for instance in this username - email table

```
mee - mee@unknown.com
mee2 - kle@unknown.com
mee3 - mee3@unknown.com
jft - jft@unknown.com
uey - uey@unknown.com
```

I want to only return mee, mee3, jft and uey where the username is contained in the email - now how do I do that?

I Could use Brian Hoovers solution, but I actually chose the following where clause

```
where email = CONCAT(`username`, '@unregistered.com')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select username, substring(email, 1, locate('@', email)- 1) from usertable
where lower(username) = lower(substring(email, 1, locate('@', email)- 1));
```

This would give you every email where the username and the beginning of the email are the same

Comment: oh I'm sorry - I dont, it's random all I know is that the email will end on @unknown.com

Comment: So, what do you know in advance?  Are you just trying to strip off the characters after the @?

Comment: yeah excactly I just want to compare the characters before @unknown.com with the username.

Comment: But that's what the query that I wrote would give you.  You just replace 'mee@%' with what ever the username you're looking for.  So, if you were looking for mee3, you would use select * from email table where email like 'mee3@%'

Comment: yeah but I'm looking for all users that have usernames equal to their email

Comment: What DB are you using?  This can be done, but it's very DB specific

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4280/discussion-between-jakob-and-brian-hoover)

Answer (score 1):

If you use MS SQL Server, to get the first part of the email use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(email, 0, CHARINDEX('@', email)) FROM EmailTable
```